# I need help with tlf fonts and as3. When I export I get an error WARNING: Multiple TLF Objects

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tlf

I'm using a custom font on my flash website and am getting an error message "WARNING: Multiple TLF objects have the same instance name.  TLF instance names must be unique.  All but one of the instance names will be renamed during export.".  Please let me know what I need to do to fix this.  It's on digital-universe-electronics.com, and you'll notice the font not working on several items, and I really need to fix it.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At least two TLFTextFields you have placed on the stage seem to have the same instance name, which is the name you entered in the properties panel of your Flash IDE.  This means that you have more than one object on the stage using the same name to be addressed by ActionScript, at the same time (it's okay to do so in different frames).

You should always make sure you have unique names for all stage instances, not just text fields.  You can use the Movie Explorer window to conveniently check for identical names.  Just double-click the instance whose name you want to change, and the properties panel will open.

You could also leave the name field blank, which causes the Flash player to assign a generic name ("instance"+number), if you don't need to have named access from ActionScript.